# Retrieve list of unique values of an attribute(column) in excel using Apache POI library

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am reading an excel file containing millions of records of a dataset for my project work. My problem is that how do I populate list of unique values that each categorical variable of a column(or attribute) can have. Is there any predefined function in the POI library that can do this task or the only option left out is to iterate over every individual record and then compare with already existing ones to determine the new ones. Thanks.

Comment: So, if there are 15 columns, do you want to end up with 15 distinct sets of unique values?

Comment: No suppose a column has only 5 values spread over all the thousands of records for that particular column then I want those 5 values to be return as a list.

Comment: Or for example, consider the target class to be containing values like "Yes","No",Maybe" then in that case for the target class column I want these three values to be returned in a suitable data structure.

Comment: Benoit's approach will work for that: declare a Set. Then, iterate through the column, and keep adding to the Set. At the end, the Set will have only unique values.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to create an object with all the column then override `hashCode` and `equals` methods for this object.

1. Parse the Excel file into a collection
2. Then iterate through the collection and add them to a `Set`.

For `YourObject` containing each column:

```
@Override
public int hashCode(){
    return new HashCodeBuilder()
        .append(column1)
        .append(column2)
        .toHashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj){
    if(obj instanceof YourObject){
        final YourObject other = (YourObject) obj;
        return new EqualsBuilder()
            .append(column1, other.column1)
            .append(column2, other.column2)
            .isEquals();
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Add each onject to a `Set`:

```
Set<YourObject> setOfObjects= new HashSet<YourObject>();
setOfObjects.add(yourObject);
```

[Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) documentation.